# Which "weasels" is Ron referring to?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry frightens Malfoy's gang using his invisibility cloak:

> Ron: **Those weasels!** Never told me about any Marauder's Map.
>
> Hermione: He won't keep it. He'll turn it over to Professor
> McGonagall.

Which "weasels" is Ron referring to?

Comment: Fred and George

Comment: Odd that Ron would use that insult, I was under the impression the Weasley children did not appreciate being compared to the rodent. I think Malfoy made the mean-spirited pun at some point?

Comment: @Aww_Geez Weasels aren't rodents; they're carnivores, specifically mustelids.

Comment: @Aww_Geez People often use insults within-group they wouldn't tolerate from out-group.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Why, you stuck-up, half-witted, scruffy-looking nerf herder! That's definitely true.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Ron is annoyed that Fred and George - who just handed Harry the Map - have never told him, *their own brother*, about the map. He's annoyed at them for opting to tell Harry and not him about it, so he's calling them weasels.

Seeing as their last name is "Weasley", "weasels" is probably an insult that's been levied very often at every member of their family. It's a safe fallback for an insult directed at his brothers for not telling him about something, especially considering that "weasel", when used in this context, means somebody who's sneaky or sly... such as hiding a magical map from your brother.